# Undefined reference in static library to global symbol included in an earlier included static library?

Tags: c, static-libraries, elf, static-linking, musl

I am trying to build an application statically for RISC-V without standard includes and without a standard lib, and instead am trying to link in a statically built musl-libc using its libc.a and crt1.o files (Note, I built crt1.o into a static library libcrt1.a).

The following is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my Makefile:

```
CC=/home/john/deps/install/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g --static -static-libgcc -nostdinc -nostdlib -I/home/john/musl-1.1.23/install/include
LDFLAGS=-L/home/john/deps/install/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/8.1.0 -L/home/john/musl-1.1.23/install/lib -lc -lgcc -lcrt1

hello.elf: hello.c
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

clean:
        rm -f hello.elf
```

When I try to make this, I get the following error:

```
/home/john/musl-1.1.23/install/lib/libcrt1_weak.a(crt1.o): In function `_start_c':
/home/john/musl-1.1.23/crt/crt1.c:18: undefined reference to `__libc_start_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'hello.elf' failed
```

However, when I inspect the symbols of libc and libcrt1, I find that __libc_start_main is a GLOBAL symbol defined in libc:

```
File: libc.a(__libc_start_main.o)
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS __libc_start_main.c
   323: 0000000000000000   112 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 __libc_start_main
```

(Here is the printout of the symbol in libcrt1 for clarity):

```
    88: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main
```

Any help understanding why this global symbol is not being resolved would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries have to at the end of the command line. ld is searching only one time for the symbols in the library.

```
LDFLAGS=-L/home/john/deps/install/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/8.1.0 -L/home/john/musl-1.1.23/install/lib -lcrt1 -lgcc -lc
```

> --library=archive
> Add archive file archive to the list of files to link. This option may be used any number of times. ld will search its path-list for
> occurrences of libarchive.a for every archive specified. On systems
> which support shared libraries, ld may also search for libraries with
> extensions other than .a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, ld
> will search a directory for a library with an extension of .so before
> searching for one with an extension of .a. By convention, a .so
> extension indicates a shared library. The linker will search an
> archive only once, at the location where it is specified on the
> command line. If the archive defines a symbol which was undefined in
> some object which appeared before the archive on the command line, the
> linker will include the appropriate file(s) from the archive. ***However,
> an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line
> will not cause the linker to search the archive again***. See the -(
> option for a way to force the linker to search archives multiple
> times. You may list the same archive multiple times on the command
> line. This type of archive searching is standard for Unix linkers.
> However, if you are using ld on AIX, note that it is different from
> the behaviour of the AIX linker.